# AWS Codebuild - Can one access last git commit message from codebuild buildspec?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

In a few of my codepipelines, I have set up E2E testing with cypress/mocha/mochawesome-reporter to run tests in the post-build section of my codebuild. Then, I added a --recursive line (see below) to take all the report materials out of the build and move them into a timestamped (see : "$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")") directory in an s3 bucket. I wanted to know if there is a way to access the last commit message (perhaps as an environmental variable or otherwise?) and add that to the name of my timestamped directory. I have read through a lot of the documentation but only see environmental variables which allow you to pull out git ID/Hash.

I know you can see the last commit message in the "Source" portion of your codepipeline (via webhooks), so maybe there is a way to propagate that information through to the build section?

Further info : The codepipelines are triggered by webhooks seeing a new push to my repo.

Have read documentation. Tried adding "printenv" in the codebuild, and then when I watched the tail logs come in, I didn't see any commit messages I could pull out.

```
 post_build:
    commands:
       - npm run ci
       - aws s3 mv mochawesome-report s3://XXX-BUCKET/reports/XXX-PRODUCT/$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M") --recursive
```

I expect there might be some possible way to pull the last git commit message out, maybe that last line in my code examples would look like :

- aws s3 mv mochawesome-report s3://XXX-BUCKET/reports/XXX-PRODUCT/$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")CODEBUILD_SRC_GIT_COMMIT_MSG?? --recursive

Comment: in this forum thread you can find lot of info https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=226646 you can indeed use the git command for that

Answer (score 1):

The script https://github.com/thii/aws-codebuild-extras provides additional environment variables in CodeBuild, including one for CODEBUILD_GIT_MESSAGE. Maybe something similar would work in CodePipeline?

Comment: It returns ``fatal: No tags can describe 'bf27############'. 
Try --always, or create some tags. ``